# differences between createTransaction and createTransactionBatch (@safe-global/protocol-kit)

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk, safe-core, batch, safe-apps-sdk

Is there a difference between:

- `createTransaction` **(used with multiple transactions (MetaTransactionData[]))**
- `createTransactionBatch`

Both seem to do the same thing but `createTransactionBatch` is not documented in the [README](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/tree/main/packages/protocol-kit) so I don't really know fur sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `createTransaction` is recommended as `createTransactionBatch` will probably be moved to a utils file

Answer (score 0):

Generally, createTransaction might handle a single transaction or an array of transactions, while createTransactionBatch typically implies batch processing of multiple transactions together.

The exact difference would depend on the implementation details in the code.